# Can my friend play Street Fighter V online from shared library?

Tags: steam, steam-family-sharing, street-fighter-v

I willingly gave out my Steam info to my friend so we can share my library and he can play Hitman 2.

What I want to know is if he could also play SFV online if the game is in my library or does he have to own the game himself for that?

Answer (score 1):

It seems like they should be able to, have they tried?

I say "seems like" because it should have the value "exfgls: Yes" like [CS: GO](https://steamdb.info/app/730/info/) does on its SteamDB page if it's not included in Family Sharing, but [Street Fighter V](https://steamdb.info/app/310950/info/) does not have that on the info page for the app.